# when i run react-native ios i am getting this error ,i am useing macbook air

Tags: react-native

```
ios/Pods/RCT-Folly/folly/io/async/VirtualEventBase.cpp normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'RCT-Folly' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)
```

I tried so many solutions but cant resolve this error

Comment: which x-code version are you using. also try to make build from x-code.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue when updating the project target OS version.

Actually Xcode will ask you to change the target OS version for the different packages, which then lead to not finding the RCT package anymore for me.

So when xcode tells you there is a good option to change the target settings for different pods, be very careful with that. Either do it step by step and try out or leave it as is, as long as it is building and running.

`yarn install` then `pod install` respectively `arch -x86_64 pod install` since I am also running on M1.

Since it might have to do something with that as well I would also disable arm64 in xcode your projects target build phases under build settings "excluded architectures" and only install pods with `arch -x86_64 pod install`.